# Optimization of several cost functions together

Tags: algorithms, optimization, convex-optimization

Say I want to minimize several functions together:

$$\min \lVert f_1\rVert, \min \lVert f_2\rVert, \min \lVert f_1-f_2\rVert$$

where $\lVert f\rVert$ is the $L_2$ norm of $f$. 
I am wondering can I simply find some equivalent process, like

$$\min(a\lVert f_1\rVert+ b \lVert f_2\rVert+ c \lVert f_1-f_2\rVert)$$ 
?

If so, is there any relations within $a$, $b$ and $c$? such as $a + b + c = 1$?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It stands to reason that each of these minimizations, separately, would result in a different point. What exactly are you hoping to achieve by optimizing all three together? A performance gain?

Comment: Background is I have two sets of medical images that are registered. If I am looking at their discrete gradient (DSG) information,  they should look similar. I want to minimize their total variation(TV) (sum of DSGs), and I also want their difference in TV not far.

Comment: In that case your best bet is indeed to minimize the linear combination of objectives, adjusting $a$, $b$, and $c$ until you arrive at a suitable result. Because the images are different, you may be able to choose $a=b=1$ and then just adjust $c$.

Comment: So if I try a bunch of a,b and c, then is there any pointers how I should tune them, except for brute force triple for loop?

Comment: There really isn't, unfortunately. Multi-objective optimization is a subject of considerable study with no easy answers in the general case.

Comment: OK. Thanks Mike. I value your opinions. I think this kind problems certainly need experiments. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no general way to do multiobjective optimization.

See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization):
"For a nontrivial multi-objective optimization problem, there does not exist a single solution that simultaneously optimizes each objective."

Comment: I think you are right. There seems not to have a closed form solution and we have to come up with something that fits the background. Thanks.